# Pentaho Filter Regexp Excel Input

Tags: regex, excel, input, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

Ok, so what I'm trying to do now is take all the information off an Excel Input (all String columns), and then of these columns I want to make an specific filter for one of them, more specific on column NO_BIEN, this specific expression.

**[0-9]+(.[0-9][0-9]?)?**

I make a Filter Rows operation and click on the REGEXP filter but I don't see where can I paste the expression because all I can see if to add a String.

[image: Filter rows screen]

Comment: If I click on the empty space a popup is brought, but I dont seem to know where to place it.  http://imgur.com/85Asvk9

Answer (score 1):

Place the regular expresssion in the filter-field "value"

[image: test value]